# Wordpress template files in subdirectory's

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, subdirectory

A while ago i started a new Wordpress project. But i got into an issue. Since there are multiple designs i need to create multiple templates for pages, posts and text format outputs for on the different page-templates.

So since the're are so many template files i wanted to create some subdirectory's. i know that since Wordpress 3.4 and higher you're able to use the subdirectory name `page-templates` for all the page templates but how could i use that for the format files and for the post files.

Yes i did try to add functions like:

```
 get_template_part('/template-parts/page-templates' , 'page');
```

And

```
require( get_template_directory() . '/template-parts/template-tags.php' );
```

The ideal directory structure i would like to create is as follows:

```
wp-content/themes/mytheme
- archive
- 404
- CSS
- JS
- Images 
- template-parts (dir)
-- page-templates (dir for page-template files.)
-- format-templates (dir for format-templates.)
-- post-templates (dir for post-templates.)
- header
- footer
```

So to be clear. I want to create the structure for template files like above. Don't mind the folders like `CSS` etc. Those are set the correct way. The intention is, after i've succesfully created the structure, to be able to select the templates like a page temple from the `/wp-admin` edit page section.

Comment: This answer to the same question explains where it is hard coded in wordpress. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/250024. However it is not a good idea mess with core wordpress files.

Comment: if you can use custom post type for your pages, you may like to use `apply_filters( "theme_{$post_type}_templates", $post_templates, $this, $post, $post_type );` and here you can write code to go deep down directory level .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`WP_Theme` class contains the method `get_page_templates()` that offers this filter:

`apply_filters( "theme_{$post_type}_templates", $post_templates, $this, $post, $post_type );`

[line 1103 of class-wp-theme.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/class-wp-theme.php#L1103)

Keeping in mind that in wordpress `post` and `page` are [`post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)s,

`add_filter( "theme_post_templates", ...` and `add_filter( "theme_page_templates",...`
should be valid.

[Under the codex's "Used By" section](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_templates/#used-by) for that method, it states:

> wp-admin/includes/template.php: page_template_dropdown()
>
> wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php: page_attributes_meta_box()

Which leads me to believe it would make them available on the `/wp-admin/` edit page section.

Info from core files regarding the filter:

```
 * Filters list of page templates for a theme.
 *
 * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$post_type`, refers to the post type.
 * @since 4.7.0 Added the `$post_type` parameter.
 *
 * @param array        $post_templates Array of page templates. Keys are filenames,
 *                                     values are translated names.
 * @param WP_Theme     $this           The theme object.
 * @param WP_Post|null $post           The post being edited, provided for context, or null.
 * @param string       $post_type      Post type to get the templates for.
```

I'm unsure if a relative uri works here or if you need `get_theme_file_path()`, but am assuming the former.

```
function deep_templates( $post_templates, $theme, $post, $post_type )
   $post_templates['/folder/folder/folder/file.php'] = "Page Style One";
   $post_templates['/folder/other-folder/file.php']  = "Page Style Two";
   return $post_templates;
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'deep_templates' );
```

AND/OR

```
add_filter( 'theme_post_templates', 'deep_templates' );
add_filter( 'theme_my-custom-cpt_templates', 'deep_templates' );
```

Comment: Thanks this does actually work perfectly. To give others a good answer i will edit yours in a second with how i've updated my functions.php to complete the sub > sub directory templates.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of what you need to do.

```
- directory1 (dir)
-- directory2 (dir)
--- template-file.php
```

To access this template with `get_template_part` you would do this:

`get_template_part( 'directory1/directory2/template', 'file' );`

`'directory1/directory2` defines the directory structure.
`template'` is the string before the `-` in the template name.
'file' is the string after the `dash` in the template name.

So in your case if you had a template file called `page-contact.php` in your `page-templates` directory, you would use.

`get_template_part('template-parts/page-templates/page' , 'contact');`

Comment: alright i understand, and could you tell me where i could place this code so that the `/wp-admin` back-end could read my template while editing a page.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I misunderstood. I thought you were referring to templates parts not complete page templates. I believe you can put templates files in your own template structure (only 1 level deep though) and the admin will pick it up as long as you add `/* Template Name: my fancy template name */` as a PHP comment at the top of the template file.

Comment: I knew that already,  and sorry for that i've already edited my question. But how about two layers deep?

Comment: Wordpress only searches for templates 1 level deep. This is hardcoded in to the core of wordpress and sadly can't be changed.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the case with you, but the templates I make are usually just structural frameworks. The majority of my important code is held in template parts, which you can put in whatever directory structure you want and then call them with `get_template_part` in your template file.

Comment: I would use template parts if it wouldn't be that there are about 30 to 40 pages on this site and about 10 different designs. It is easier to use full templates for the outer design, Format templates for the content design and post templates for the post designs then use about 100 different template parts since these are only parts of code.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question that already has an answer but it wasn't the solution I was looking for. Adding another option in case anyone else is searching for a way to move all WordPress template files to a subfolder. Found this [code for changing the default folder for WordPress template files](https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/ffhjvw/moving_wordpress_theme_template_files_to/) on Reddit and made a few small adjustments. This code can be placed in the functions.php of your theme or child theme.

```php
/**
 * Tell WordPress that we have moved default template files to the page-templates folder.
 * Based on code from: https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/ffhjvw/moving_wordpress_theme_template_files_to/
 *
 * Related posts with other solutions:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589503/moving-wordpress-theme-template-files-to-subdirectory
 * https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/custom-post-type-templates-from-plugin-folder
 * https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291725/store-page-template-files-in-a-subfolder
 * https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/312159/how-to-move-page-template-files-like-page-slug-php-to-a-sub-directory/312611#312611
 * 
 * Template hierarchy info: 
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template_hierarchy/
 * https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8.1/src/wp-includes/template.php
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/organizing-theme-files/#page-templates-folder
 *
 * @param array $templates A list of candidates template files.
 * @return string Full path to template file.
 */
function change_template_path($templates) {

  // The custom sub-directory for page templates in your theme. 
  $custom_sub_dir = 'page-templates';

  // Don't use the custom template directory in unexpected cases.
  if(empty($templates) || ! is_array($templates)) {
    return $templates;
  }

  $page_template_id = 0;
  $count = count( $templates);
  if($templates[0] === get_page_template_slug()) {
    // if there is a custom template, then our page-{slug}.php template is at the next index
    $page_template_id = 1;
  }

  // The last one in $templates is page.php, single.php, or archives.php depending on the type of template hierarchy being read.
  // Paths of all items starting from $page_template_id will get updated
  for($i = $page_template_id; $i < $count ; $i++) {
    $templates[$i] = $custom_sub_dir . '/' . $templates[$i];
  }

  return $templates;
}

// Add filters to override the path for each WP template hierarchy.
// These are all the template hierarchy filters. You should probably only override the ones you need.
add_filter('404_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('archive_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('attachment_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('author_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('category_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('date_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('embed_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('frontpage_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('home_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
// If you override the index hierarchy, be sure to add an index.php template in your custom template folder.
add_filter('index_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path'); 
add_filter('page_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('paged_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('privacypolicy_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('search_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('single_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('singular_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('tag_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
add_filter('taxonomy_template_hierarchy', 'change_template_path');
```

Answer (score 0):

wrapping up the accepted answer in a working piece of code :

```
<?php

/* Pages templates in sub folders */
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

add_filter('theme_page_templates', function($post_templates) {
  $directories = glob(get_template_directory() . '/pages/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
  
  foreach ($directories as $dir) {
    $templates = glob($dir.'/*.php');

    foreach ($templates as $template) {
      if (preg_match('|Template'.' '.'Name: (.*)$|mi', file_get_contents($template), $name)) {
        $post_templates['/pages/'.basename($dir).'/'.basename($template)] = $name[1];
      }
    }
  }

  return $post_templates;
});
```

This could be enhanced with a recursive function, for now it only adds :

```
./pages/\*/\*.php
```

Comment: note : the inserted space, in the preg match regex param, prevents this piece of code of being detected as a template itself

Answer (score -1):

[get_template_part will only work as part of a WordPress THEME](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/).

What you'll want to do is create your own WordPress theme, (which lives in wp-content/themes/ ) which you can then use for any PHP templates, CSS resources etc. that you want.

You can check out how to build a WordPress theme and include everything [in the codex here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Comment: Yes this is my own build theme. It is already build and works with the templates files etc. The only problem i'm having is with re-organizing the theme. As i've told i only need to know how to use the custom directory's. A link to the full wordpress codex is NOT a solution.

Comment: What I'm saying is that using get_template_part outside of a theme folder will not work, as the file won't be located.  In that case you'll need to use traditional PHP include/requires that are outside of the WordPress framework.

Comment: this is all inside the theme folder. Not ouside.

Comment: That's unclear in your question, you should have :

- wp-content

-- themes

--- CSS

....

WizardCoder's answer above should work

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a Template file(inside "page-templates" directory) for each diferent design you will have.

For creating a template file accessible from de Backend(wp-admin) you need to add:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: TEMPLATE-NAME
*/
?>
```

in the top of each file(template). Then inside each file, you can add the blocks or modules of the design using get_template_part() function.

Comment: This isn't the question. I've told in my question that i am aware of that already and that i'm using it. What i want to create is a way to use `page-templates` in sub > sub directory's.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you want the templates inside a 2 depth directory of the theme. I am afraid there is no way to do it without modifying the core of WP.